# how to get the roles and username of the person who reacted to my embed in discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
    suggestEmbed.add_field(name='Ticket ID: ', value = f'{uniqueID}', inline=False)    
    message = await channel.send(embed = suggestEmbed)
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
 
    sendEmbed.set_author(name = f'suggested by {ctx.message.author}', icon_url = f'{ctx.author.avatar_url}')
    sendEmbed.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
    
    def check (reaction, user):
        return not user.bot and message == reaction.message
    
    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add',check=check,timeout=604800)
        while reaction.message == message:
            if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":
                await ctx.send(" Yay! Your suggestion has been approved, We thank you for your valuable time!")
                await channel.send(f'suggestion of {ctx.message.author}, with ID: {uniqueID} has been approved, this post will no longer be active')
                return
            if str(reaction.emoji) == "❌":
                await ctx.send("‍♀️‍♀️ Sorry! Your suggestion has not been approved, We thank you for your valuable time!")
                message1 = await ctx.send(embed = sendEmbed)
                await channel.send(f'suggestion of {ctx.message.author}, with ID: {uniqueID} has not been approved, this post will no longer be active')
                return
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Your suggestion was timed out. Please try again!")
        return
```

I want to know the role/Username of the person who reacts to my embed. (made this using dicord.py). is there a way I can access it using ctx? or any other way that I don't know of.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `discord.js`?

Comment: just me thinking, people might help me out on this

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting `user` from the `bot.wait_for`, you can simply access the username using one of the two:

```py
username =  user.display_name
#or
username = user.name
```

and the roles you can access using:

```py
roles = user.roles #user.roles returns a list because the user can have multiply roles.
#Attention! This will raise an error if the reaction was in a dmchannel
```

---

### References

- [user.name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user%20name#discord.User.name)S
- [user.display_name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user%20name#discord.User.display_name)
- [member.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member%20roles#discord.Member.roles)